# Alien or parasite crawls into mouth of women movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember this scene where some sort of alien or slug (grey in color) comes out of the ventilation system and crawls into the mouth of a sleeping woman.

I think it is a more recent film. Any idea of title?

Comment: recent meaning last 5, 10, 20 years?

Comment: Funnily enough, I think there are a lot of scenes of stuff crawling into women's mouths, so you may want to provide more details, if the current answer didn't get it.

Comment: Now I want watch Stargate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember a movie like this. [*Proteus* (1995)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114196/). Some gray, slug-like creature lowered itself out of a ventilation grate above a bed in which a woman is recovering/sleeping. That's the only part of the movie I remember.

> Group of heroin smugglers finds shelter on abandoned oil rig after their ship had exploded. Soon they find that the oil rig was just cover for biological experiment. One of the results is Charlie - shape-shifting monster with ability to absorb the memory of its victims. However, even such creatures have their own bad habits.

Trailer:

Comment: Yes that's it. That actually is also the only part I remembered. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*[The Hidden](http://thecinematologist.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/hidden.html)* has a grey slug alien that crawls into people's mouths and some of the people were women (Claudia Christian, for one memorable one).

> These parasitic aliens come in two forms: slug-like organism, or golden vapor. In either case, the parasite enters the host through the mouth and is somehow able to control their body completely. The subjective experience of the host is not known, as no one has lived through an infestation to relate their experience.

[image: Slug image]

Comment: ewww. Double ewww, actually

Answer (score 2):

Very common theme, a few come to mind. Slither (2006) but the slugs are red. Then there is The Faculty (98). Night of the Creeps (80s) has grey alien slugs and Shiver (70s).

All good horror/comedy with the same slug alien theme, and frankly all great movies. I think each has a heating duct scene and the slugs enter the people through the mouth.